# Find known number of missing natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, integer-programming

Given a set $S$ of distinct natural numbers, we know that a subset $T$ that is $S$ with at most $k$ number of elements missing. Let $M_k := \big\{m_j\big|d_j = \sum_{i\in T}i^j, j\in \{1,2,...,k\}\,\big\}$. Does $M_k$ uniquely determine the missing at most $k$ natural numbers, or another word, $T$?

Ross Millikan made the connection of this problem to the moment problem by viewing it as the discrete version of it.

We can also formulate this problem as a binary linear equation or inequality problem.

For $k=2$, I have proved the claim. If $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_2,b_2)$ are two pairs of missing numbers, $a_1+a_2 = b_1+b_2$ and $a_1^2+a_2^2 = b_1^2+b_2^2$. Equivalently $a_1-b_1 = b_2-a_2$ and $(a_1-b_1)(a_1+b_1) = (b_2-a_2)(b_2+a_2)$. We conclude $a_1=b_2$ and $a_2 = b_1$. So the missing numbers are uniquely determined if the two moments are.

But the above method does not seem to carry over easily for $k>2$. Please help.

Comment: @AhaanRungta: As I have mentioned in the last paragraph of the question, I have tried and succeeded in proving $k=2$. The same method does not seem to work for $k>2$.

Comment: Since the sums over all of $S$ are the same regardless of $T$, we can make it $D_k := \big\{d_j\big|d_j =\sum_{i\in T}i^j, j\in \{1,2,...,k\}\,\big\}$ and now we can ignore $S$ and just ask if $T$ is determined as a subset of $\Bbb N$.  This is the discrete version of the problem of moments.

Comment: Right, my question was if you have tried some other method for $k>2$?

Comment: I think you can argue that the [Vandemonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is nonsingular and therefore you can solve the problem uniquely, but am not sure.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Now I do not think Vandemonde matrix method is right any more.

Comment: Crossposting http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150045/find-known-number-of-missing-natural-numbers

Comment: Might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3492302/562769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the $k$ missing numbers as $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_k$. Then we know $\sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_i^j}$ for $j=1, 2, \ldots , k$. Using [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), we may determine $\sum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2< \ldots<i_l \leq k}{x_{i_1}x_{i_2} \ldots x_{i_l}}$ for $l=1, 2, \ldots , k$, so we may use Vieta's formula to get a monic polynomial of degree $k$ with $x_1, \ldots , x_k$ as roots. This uniquely determines what $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_k$ are.